# How to pass session variables in JDBC url properly?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have to increase group_concat_max_len.
I cannot do it by preparestatement, and also I cannot do it in mysql my.conf file.

I found on mysql docs that there is an option to pass session variables in url.
But there is no example, I tried to do it like that:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx/dbName?sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len:204800
```

and I have this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':204800' at line 1
```

And also I tried it like like this:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx/dbName?sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len,204800
```

because the official docs says:

```
sessionVariables

A comma-separated list of name/value pairs to be sent as SET SESSION ... to the server when the driver connects.

Since version: 3.1.8
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx/dbName?sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len=204800
```

Comment: @cristan, i am trying to set block_encryption_mode through the technique you shared above like this:

datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=Block_encryption_mode='aes-256-cbc'

But is is working on when writing the data, reading the data is not working in aes_256, it is still working in aes_128. Do you happen to know the solution to this ?

Answer (score 14):

If you need to add more than one session parameter you can do it like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?sessionVariables=FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0&sessionVariables=SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0
```

Comment: Could you explain what is different in your URL compared to the OP's URL and how does it help?

Comment: If you have a look at the official documentation from Oracle here [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) you will find out that it's a kind of confusing. It is stated that the parameters should be given as comma separated list of values which actually isn't clear. The example above makes it clear how one could set two or more session parameters.

Answer (score 7):

The [MySQL Connector/J Configuration Properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) documentation has been updated since with a better description, especially when it comes to setting multiple system variables in the connection URL :

> sessionVariables
>
> A comma or semicolon separated list of name=value pairs to be sent as
>   SET [SESSION] ... to the server when the driver connects.
>
> Since version: 3.1.8

Which results in URLs like this one :

```
jdbc:mysql://xxxx.xx.xx.xx/dbName?sessionVariables=group_concat_max_len=204800,bulk_insert_buffer_size=42
```

Semicolons can be used instead of commas. A mix of the two can be used within the same URL.

This will only work for system variables that have a `SESSION` scope (you can find out which ones can be set at `SESSION`-level by looking at the list of [Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)).
The connection will fail if the variable doesn't exist, if it is not a server system variable or if its scope is `GLOBAL`-only.