# JPA: How to set MySQL session variables?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I need to set a mysql session variable for my application to work with a MariaDB Galera Cluster as expected. The SQL call is: `SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 1`. It shall be set at all times when the application uses the database. I am using EclipseLink as the JPA provider.

My question is: What is the best way to achieve this?

**Option 1: EclipseLink Session Customizer**

Register a session customizer in `persistence.xml`:

```
public class SessionCustomizerImpl implements org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer {

    private final static String WSREP_SYNC_WAIT_CHECK_SQL = "SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wsrep_sync_wait'";
    private final static String WSREP_SYNC_WAIT_SET_SQL = "SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 1";

    @Override
    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        Vector result = session.executeSQL(WSREP_SYNC_WAIT_CHECK_SQL);
        if ((result != null) && !result.isEmpty()) {
            session.executeNonSelectingSQL(WSREP_SYNC_WAIT_SET_SQL);
            // Galera connection detected; wsrep_sync_wait set to 1
        } else {
            // No Galera connection detected; wsrep_sync_wait not set
        }

    }
}
```

This does not work for me. Querying the session variable from an EntityManager returns a value of `0`.

**Option 2: EntityManager factory**

Every time a new EntityManager is created, the SQL is executed.

```
public class SyncWaitEntityManagerFactory implements Factory<EntityManager> {
    private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Inject
    public SyncWaitEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager provide() {
        final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        // set it
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.createNativeQuery("SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 1").executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        return em;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(EntityManager instance) {
        if (instance.isOpen()) {
            instance.close();
        }
    }

}
```

This works, but I'm not sure if it is overkill. Also, I am worried about the cost of the transaction, which is only required by `Query#executeUpdate()`, but not by the actual SQL call.

**Option 3: Via JDBC URL**

Appending the variable and value to the JDBC URL (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425584/295962%20here) for details):

```
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://db.example.test:3306/"+ JDBC_DB 
            +"?sessionVariables=wsrep_sync_wait=1";
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", jdbcUrl);
    p.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", JDBC_USER);
    p.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", JDBC_PASSWORD);
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU", p);

    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Nice solution. Works for me; no effort, no transaction necessary. Downside: I can't catch exceptions (example: check first if the variable exists, then set it -- allows deployment of the code on systems that don't support/use this specific variable).

Comment: This has been very informative to me. I had a similar problem and went with Option 2. I suggest you post this a post on your personal blog or something.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use an aspect to execute a query every time a getConnection() is called which is for every transaction basically (the aspect is set after the call so that we have a valid connection object):

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class CustomConnectionPreparer implements ConnectionPreparer
{
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* *.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
    public Connection prepare(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        // execute the query (also exception handling)
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute("SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 1");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And before you return the connection to the caller you execute your query and you should always have that value set.